# Return variable from one function to another in powershell

Tags: function, powershell, variables, return

I am inside function #1 and triggering function #2. Function #2 has a variable that I want to get back into function #1 and use it.

My output ends up being:

```
hey there
var is:
```

What I want is the output to be:

```
var is: hey there
```

Why is it that I can feed a function a variable, and it uses it, but when I change that variable in the #2 function, it does not change the variable after it `returns`?

```
$var = $null

function one() {

two($var)

write-host "var is:" $var

}


function two($var){

$var = "hey there"

return($var)

}

clear
one
```

Comment: You're not returning `$var`.

Comment: @DanielMann if I type "return($var)", it only outputs $var, it does not change the variable when it actually returns.

Comment: @Aaron variables in powershell are locally scoped, meaning that changing the value of a variable with the name `var` inside `two` won't change the value of `var` inside the calling scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your `two` function to actually return a value:

```bsh
function two {
  $var = "hey there"

  return $var
}
```

and then update the `one` function to actually "capture" the output value by assigning it to a variable:

```bsh
function one {
  # PowerShell doesn't use parentheses when calling functions
  $var = two

  Write-Host "var is:" $var
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if you call another function and that function has 2 or more variables in it? I know you set $var = two , so say function two has 2 variables in it, how do you get them back?

Comment: `$var1,$var2 = two`

Comment: @Aaron Might be worth reading [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return) as well - in PowerShell you don't need to specify the `return` keyword in order to pass data back to the caller (which may be slightly confusing at first)

Answer (score 0):

If you really do want to reach up and change a variable in the scope of your caller, you can...

Set-Variable -Name $Name -Value $Value -Scope 1

It's a little meta/quirky but I've run into cases where it seemed proper. For example, I once wrote a function called `RestoreState` that I called at the beginning of several functions exported from a module to handle some messy reentrant cases; one of the things it did is reach up and set or clear `$Verbose` in the calling function's scope.